# Receive Json array in Javascript and ouput the result

Tags: php, arrays, json, ajax

If i don't use the var productOj and i output the response. innerHTML= this.response;
I will respond this{"detail":"this is detail", "link":"/link/here"} so the response come back in json but i want to access individual detail and link and output them somewhere else.

```
    function getProduct(productName) {
    if (productName == "0") {
        document.getElementById("instr_text").innerHTML = "Please Select A Product";
        return;
    } else {
       // document.getElementById("orderSummary").innerHTML = str;

        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                //document.getElementById("orderSummary").innerHTML = "success";
              var productObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                document.getElementById("detail").innerHTML = productObj.detail;


            } else {
                //document.getElementById("orderSummary").innerHTML = "failure" + this.readyState + this.status;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "getinfo.php?productName=" + productName,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is JQuery an option? I think you'll find a JQuery implementation to be much simpler.

Comment: I know but for some reason i don't like jquery

Answer (score 1):

It might look something like this.

```
var productObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
var productHtml = "";
productObj.forEach(product => productHtml += "<p>" + product.detail + "</p>")
document.getElementById("detail").innerHTML = productHtml;
```

What you're doing is going through each element in your `productObj` array and creating the HTML that you're looking for. Once you have the blob of html you want, you append it in the div of your choice. You can repeat / modify this process to access `link` as well.

Comment: good idea. I gave it a try, i did not work but i think i wrongly implement it. I will try to find out why it did not output anything.